# How to get the current app in open in menu in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want my app to be listed in "Open in" menu. I Registered for the supported doc.My app gets listed in "Open in" menu of the other app.But I want to get it listed in my app's "Open in" menu as well. How to do that ?

Comment: For the "Open In" to show on a file in your app, it would mean that the file is already open in your app, right? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have two section in my app one is post section and other is chat section.

Comment: The "Open In" menu is meant to open a document in another app, and that is what your users will expect, they'll never think to look there if they want to send a document they found in a post through the chat, you should implement your own UI for that.

Comment: I have to preview the document. I can not implement my own controller for that. I have to user UIDocumentInteractionController.